# Upwards Combobox in EXTJS 4.1

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, safari, extjs4.1

I developed an application in EXTJS 4.1, in which on dynamic selection from drop down, the pdf data is fetched in the iframe.
In chrome, it works fine but in IE10 and Safari, dropdown gets hidden behind the default iframe pdf window of the browser. 
Can anyone help to open the combo-box upwards ?
Is there any other solution?

I have tried with alignTo and listalign but it's not working.
Please share an example code if available for this.
Thanks in advance.
Code :

```
{
    xtype:'combobox',
    id:'WeekNumCmb1',
    cls:'comboBoxCls1',
    //width: 100,
    flex:1,
    store: weekList,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'weekNum',
    valueField: 'weekNum',
    value: currweek,
    editable:false,
    maxHeight : 10,
    alignTo:("tr?"),
    listAlign: 'c?',
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `alignTo` try `pickerAlign : 'bl-tl?'` , it will open combobox list upward.